# How Can newInstance() Work If There Is No Constructor Written?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, instance, instantiation

I've come across an interesting snippet of Java code. I researched what newInstance() is, and it's meant to be a way to avoid calling a constructor and create a new instance of an object. But looking at the example code I don't understand one thing: Why is there no constructor needed?

```
    public class SimpleContentFragment extends WebViewFragment {

      protected static SimpleContentFragment newInstance(String file) {
        SimpleContentFragment f=new SimpleContentFragment();

        Bundle args=new Bundle();

        args.putString(KEY_FILE, file);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return(f);
      }
    }
```

No where else in this code is there a constructor created. There is no

```
public SimpleContentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
```

as I would expect.

So could you clarify what is going on in the static method with newInstance? How come it can call `new SimpleContentFragment()` when the constructor was never written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because Java will create a default, no-arguments constructor if none is provided. It will set all reference fields to `null`, numeric types to 0, and booleans to `false`, *and invoke the superclass constructor*.

[JLS 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor is implicitly declared. The form of the default
>   constructor for a top level class, member class, or local class is as
>   follows:
>
> - The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (§6.6).
> - The default constructor has no formal parameters, except in a non-private inner member class, where the default constructor
>     implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately
>     enclosing instance of the class (§8.8.1, §15.9.2, §15.9.3).
> - The default constructor has no throws clauses.
> - If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default
>     constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no
>     arguments.